# Как просмотреть реализацию шаблона SelectionBoxItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть шаблон

```
ContentPresenter
```

и для него есть шаблон

```
ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
```

Как мне посмотреть реализацию шаблона "SelectionBoxItemTemplate"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не шаблон, это свойство родительского контрола

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо! Но можно ли его как то посмотреть?

Comment: Что значит посмотреть? Вы шаблон какого контрола редактируете?

Comment: @АндрейNOP ContentPresenter я редактирую. а он в свою очередь внутри combobox

Comment: Вот `SelectionBoxItemTemplate` это *свойство* `ComboBox`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.selectionboxitemtemplate?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо, но есть ли способ просмотреть свойство средствами visual studio?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84675/discussion-between---and--nop).

Comment: Что значит посмотреть свойство? Вы хотите узнать какое значение в нем лежит во время исполнения? или что?

Comment: @АндрейNOP думаю да.

Comment: Можно поставить брейкпоинт и посмотреть, можно с помощью окна Live Property Explorer посмотреть

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо!